# Program to add together a series of number

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops

> I am writing a program that will add together a series of
>   numbers a user inputs until the user enters a rogue value of 0. The
>   program will then display the total.

```
user_input = None
total_sum = 0
while user_input != 0:
    user_input = input("Enter a number:")
    total_sum = total_sum + user_input 

# Sample output:
# Enter a number: 5
# Enter a number: 50
# Enter a number: 10
# Enter a number: 0
# The total sum of the numbers are 65
print("The total sum of the numbers are {}".format(total_sum))
```

The error that keeps coming up is :

```
total_sum = total_sum + user_input
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`input` returns a string, even if it's a string that contains a number (e.g., "5"). You need to explicitly convert it to an `int`:

```
user_input = int(input("Enter a number: "))
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to cast the input to an int

```
user_input = int(user_input )
```

Comment: Close: `user_input = int(user_input)`

Comment: Strictly speaking you don't cast values in python, you send them to a constructor function that returns a new value of the appropriate type

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse String value to Integer value.

In your case, `user_input` is String Value.

To parse String value to Integer you need to use `int(user_input)` instead of `user_input`.

total_sum = total_sum + int(user_input)  //Like this

Answer (score 0):

input("Enter a number") returns a string which means user_input is of type string.
So you need to cast user_input to int in order to add. i.e. `total_sum = total_sum + parseInt(user_input)`